# updating x axis label in nvd3 dynamically

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to update the x axis labels in nvd3 based on a value but my x axis `axisLable` returns the entire function in the chart and not just the string...how do I do it so that it just return the string?

```
    $scope.options_scn_cst_compare = {
        chart: {
            type: "multiBarChart",
            x: function(d){ return d.x; },
            y: function(d){ return d.values; },
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: function(d) {

                        if (yAxistm.tm === 'yr') {

                            return "Time (Years)";

                        } else if (yAxistm.tm === 'qtr') {

                            return "Time (Quarterly)";

                        } else if (yAxistm.tm === 'mth') {

                            return "Time (Montly)";

                        };

                    }
           .....
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

if your objective is to give X-axis label dynamically, you can do following.

```
// Generate chart
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart();
// based on some value update the X-axes label.
if (yAxistm.tm === 'yr') {
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Yearly");
} else if (yAxistm.tm === 'qtr') {
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Quaterly");
} else if (yAxistm.tm === 'mth') {
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel("Monthly");
};
```